# Why are Tarantellas usually in a minor key?

Tags: composition

Why are Tarantellas usually written in a minor key? Is this an unwritten convention?

Comment: I'm not posting as an answer because I'm not sure, I studied the Tarantella years ago, but I suspect that the original dance started with a specific piece of music that was in Minor, and when the dance caught on and more versions were written the minor sound became part of the style.

Comment: It may also have something to do with instruments' limitations. I'm specifically thinking of diatonic accordions and the zuffolo. But I don't know enough about those or about the history of Italian folk to judge how important this aspect was.

Comment: There's a book about Tarantellas, [https://openlibrary.org/books/OL26943908M/Global_tarantella](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL26943908M/Global_tarantella), it may (or may not) have the answers you're looking for!

Comment: I expect it is due to their being associated with spiders whose poison was said to make victims dance wildly then die.